# How to sum two rows of a 2D array element by element like a sum of vectors in C language?

Tags: c, arrays, sum, rows

I would like to know if there is any simple way to sum two rows of a 2D array in C without using a loop. I got the following sample code in the main function

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (*A)[i] = drand48();
    (*B)[i] = drand48();
}
```

I'm using two pointers (A and B) to an array of length 3, and after initializing them with random numbers I want to sum them in a single sentence (like a vector sum). Let C be another pointer to an array of length 3. I have tried

```
(*C) = (*A) + (*B);
```

But I'm getting an error with that. In fortran, one can do it simply by putting:

```
C = A + B
```

Assuming A, B, and C are arrays of the same length, and both A and B are initilized. Or, if we want to sum two rows of a 2Darray, we can put:

```
C = A(i,:) + A(j,:)
```

which sum the row i to the row j.

So, there's a analogous way in C??

Thaks for your help.

Comment: The analogous way in C is to use a loop.

Comment: What is the error that you get for your attempt `(*C) = (*A) + (*B);`? From the way you fill the arrays `(*A)[i]` I assume the variables in that scope are declared as `double **A`. If `C` is then declared as `double *C` this would indeed result in an erro

Comment: @Pankrates. No. I'm declaring A and B as pointer to arrays:

Comment: yes and that is equal to `double **A`

Comment: @jlahd. So it can't be done in a clean sentence like in my fortran example? Well, thanks jlahd.

Comment: @Pankrates. So what is wrong is my sintax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you should understand:  First, fortran compiles a loop for you, so when its code runs it is still looping through the data.  Second, an optimizer might do some work for you by "un-rolling" the loop.  You could write your code that essentially unrolls a small loop, as:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    C[i][0] = A[i][0] + B[i][0];
    C[i][1] = A[i][1] + B[i][1];
    C[i][2] = A[i][2] + B[i][2];

  }
```

However, the **same** number of adds is still executed whether you code in Fortran, Matlab (a vector oriented language) or C (with or without loop unrolling).

Answer (score 0):

I got this to function.
More or less, there is an error in the sumline at the end of each line.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main ()
   //2D_Array. Create 2D array . Multiplication in each array slot.
   //KHO2016.no4. mingw (TDM-GCC-32) . c-ansi .
   {
   //Declare
   int a,b,c,d,sum;
   int k,l,num_array[50][50];

   //vaulate
   jump1 :
   printf ("Coordinat system Descartes\nBasically two FOR-loops.\n\n");
   printf ("Plot X no. of Columns, Horizontal axis. Then Y no. of Rows, Vertical axis\n:\n");
   scanf ("%d %d",&a,&b); //a = vertical , b=Horizontal.
   printf ("\nPlot two no. to be multipled\n:\n");
   scanf ("%d %d",&c,&d);

   //calculate
   for (l=0;l<b;l++) // l counts lines or on Y axis .
   {for (k=0;k<a;k++) // k counts colums (on each line) .
   printf ("[Y%d] [X%d] (%d * %d = %d)\t: ",l,k,c++,d,c*(d));
   sum = (sum+(c*d++));
   printf ("sum %d",sum);
   printf ("\n");}

   printf ("\n");
   goto jump1;  

   //terminate
   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one can select a coordinate,
and obtain the value of the selected coordinate.
But no sum of each line .

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main ()
   //2D_Array.(float). Select Coordinate, and obtain slot Value .
   //KHO2016.no6. mingw (TDM-GCC-32) . c-ansi . 
   {
   //declare
   int aa,c,d,p,q;
   float j,ar_d[10][10];

   //valuate
   jump0:
   printf ("Select 1, 2, 3, 4 : ");
   scanf ("%d",&aa);
   if (aa==1&&2&&3)
   goto jump0;

   //calculate
   if (aa==4)
   {for (c=0;c<10;c++)
   for (d=0;d<10;d++)
   ar_d[c][d]=(float)d/c;

   for (c=0;c<10;c++)
   {for (d=0;d<10;d++)
   printf ("(Y%d X%d.%.1d/%.1d= %.2f) ",c,d,c,d,ar_d[c][d]);
   printf ("SumLine1(%d)/(%d) = %.2f\n",c,d,j);
   j=(float)d/(c+1);}

   printf ("\nSelect a Coordinate : first X then Y\n"); 
   scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);
   printf ("Coordinate X[%d],Y[%d] has this value : %f\n",p,q,ar_d[q][p]);}
   goto jump0;

   //terminate
   return 0;
   }
```